# I run my first tomcat and i got an error, what should i do?

Tags: windows, tomcat, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpM7y.png)

I got this problem, when first run tomcat, i knew that the first running have always problem, but i did not found resolve for the windows user.

```
Error running 'Unnamed':..port out of range-1
```

what should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please post your code instead of an image? Please read this to know how to Post a Question https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Tomcat installation folder, go to "server.xml" file and change:

from:

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

To:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: Ty, very much, i also find another solution
you can print 1 instead of -1.